# pandas merge resulting in duplicated columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `pandas 1.4.3` and `python 3.9.13`

I am creating some data frames which are identical as follows:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_4 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

datasets = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]
```

Now I am trying to merge them all in a single data frame on `col1`. So,I do the following:

```
from functools import reduce

df_merged = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left, right,on=['col1'], how='outer', suffixes=["_x", "_y"]), datasets)
```

So, I am trying to basically keep all the columns but just use some suffixes so that they stay unique. However, the issue is that since it is more than two dataframes, this ends up resulting in duplicated columns as:

```
   col1  col2_x  col2_y  col2_x  col2_y
0     1       3       3       3       3
1     2       4       4       4       4
```

I was wondering what would be the best way to do such a merge while ensuring no columns are dropped and duplicates are conserved properly with incrementally adding suffixes...

**EDIT**

At the moment, I am now doing it with a loop as:

```
merged = datasets[0]
for i in range(1, len(datasets)):
    merged = pd.merge(merged, datasets[i], how='outer', on=['col1'], suffixes=[None, f"_{str(i)}"])
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Actually nothing but it came to me while I was typing the question. Just wondering now if there is a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit cumbersome solution:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_1.attrs['name']='1'
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_2.attrs['name']='2'
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_3.attrs['name']='3'
df_4 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_4.attrs['name']='4'

datasets = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]
from functools import reduce

def mrg (left,right):
    return pd.merge(left, right,on=['col1'], how='outer', suffixes=["_"+str(left.attrs.get('name')), "_"+str(right.attrs.get('name'))])

df_merged = reduce(lambda left,right: mrg(left,right), datasets)
```